# Equivalent for statement <value/> in spring xml configuration

Tags: java, spring

I find this spring xml configuration:

```
<bean class="..." id="...">
    <property name="...">
         <array>
              <value/>
         </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Is `<value/>` statement the same with `null` value? Or with empty value `""`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `<value/>` is equivalent to empty string `""`.

It is same:

```
<value/>
<value></value>
```

In xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd we may read about that:

> Denotes a Java null value. Necessary because an empty "value" tag
>       will resolve to an empty String, which will not be resolved to a
>       null value unless a special PropertyEditor does so.